# how can i tak all record from parent table and specific record from child table based on some values in one view

Tags: mysql, sql-server, relational-database

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bwhh.jpg]
I need takes all record from rooms_tbl table and take some record from aqed_tbl table based on (state) values 
state values : rested,busy,finished ,deleted

```
 where state=rested or state=busy
```

how can i do this in one view ???

Comment: You don't give a lot of details on your question. What columns does the parent table and the child table have? What is the expected result based on specific data that you should give?

Comment: all columns from rooms_tbl and all columns from aqed_tbl

Comment: You probably don't really want all columns as that is not useful if you don't need them. We can help you but with what you have posted so far it is impossible to understand what you want. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the answer to your question is the following SQL:

```
select rm.*, ag.*
from rooms_tbl rm
     inner join aged_tbl ag on rm.id = ag.room_id
where ag.state in ('rested', 'busy')
```

If we need all rooms even if they don't have an aged_tbl entry, then this statement should have an *outer join*:

```
select rm.*, ag.*
from rooms_tbl rm
     left join aged_tbl ag on rm.id = ag.room_id
where ag.state in ('rested', 'busy')
```

Comment: this is true but i need all rooms even if this rooms is not related with aqed_tbl

Comment: Then we need a left join

Comment: i use right outer join , it will comme also the rooms that are not related with aqed_tbl ,but i need the rooms even related with 'deleted' or 'finsihed' value but not take aqed_tbl rows for these where state='deleted' or finished just rooms_tbl rows for this state

Comment: You have to give a full example with data on your question and an expected result if you want a completely correct answer.

Comment: have you had skype for helping me

Comment: No. Stackoverflow is for giving answers to real questions. If you take real time to write a correct question, then people will spend real time and try to help you as much as they can. It is up to you.